# CMake's find_library() apparently doesn't locate libraries

Tags: c++, cmake, libraries, ogre

I want CMake to find three static libraries in the same folder. This is the portion of my CMakeLists.txt I'm struggling with:

```
# Dependencies' directories
set(OGRE3D_DIR "D:/Data/Libs/ogre3D-1.10")

# Required libraries
find_library(OGREMAIN_LIB
        NAMES OgreMain OgreMain_d
        HINTS "${OGRE3D_DIR}/lib/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")

find_library(OGREOVERLAY_LIB
        NAMES OgreOverlay OgreOverlay_d
        HINTS "${OGRE3D_DIR}/lib/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")

find_library(OIS_LIB
        NAMES OIS OIS_d
        HINTS "${OGRE3D_DIR}/lib/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")

# Target
add_executable(Test Main.cpp)

# Library linking
target_link_libraries(Test
        ${OGREMAIN_LIB}
        ${OGREOVERLAY_LIB}
        ${OIS_LIB})
```

For some reason, the three variables `OGREMAIN_LIB`, `OGREOVERLAY_LIB` and `OIS_LIB` are all set to NOTFOUND, but if I try to print them I find they're set to the expected path (even the correct one between the suffixed and non-suffixed name is picked). All libraries are obviously actually in the expected path.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: The results of `find_library()` calls are cached, but it should try to find it again if it was not found. So during your tests did you always start from an empty binary output directory? During the setup of your project - while still testing your `CMakeLists.txt` - I would recommend to add e.g. `unset(OGREMAIN_LIB CACHE)` before the `find_library()` calls to force CMake to search for the library each time.

Comment: `... the three variables OGREMAIN_LIB, OGREOVERLAY_LIB and OIS_LIB are all set to NOTFOUND, but if I try to print them I find they're set ...` - So, are these variable `-NOTFOUND` or set to some path? How do you check them (via `message()`, in CMake cache, etc.)?

Comment: For what concerns erasing the cache, I do it via CLion's interface just before reloading the project (which invokes CMake), but they end up set to <NAME>-NOTFOUND in CMake's cache (also inspected via CLion's graphical interface). As for printing their names, I use `message(STATUS "path: ${OGREMAIN_LIB}")` (etc.) after the last `find_library()` statement, and the expected path gets printed.

Comment: re: "What am I doing wrong here?" -- I hope you aren't using the Visual Studio generator, since it isn't valid to read `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` from a multi-config generator. You'll have to set the `IMPORTED_LOCATION_<CFG>` properties on an imported target.

Comment: Also, Ogre3D (even 1.10) includes a CMake package config script. You would surely be better served using that than trying to do everything manually! https://ogrecave.github.io/ogre/api/1.10/setup.html

Answer (score 0):

What about adding ${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX} and ${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX} like so:

```
find_library(OGREMAIN_LIB
    NAMES ${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX}OgreMain${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX} ${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_PREFIX}OgreMain_d${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}
    HINTS "${OGRE3D_LIB_DIR}")
```